# What constraint can't be written as a table constraint?

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I am reading the Postgres 7.3 [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/ddl-alter.html#:~:text=To%20add%20a%20not%2Dnull,before%20it%20can%20be%20added) to add a constraint to a PostgreSQL table.

It says:

> To add a not-null constraint, which cannot be written as a table constraint, use this syntax:
>
> ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN product_no SET NOT NULL;
>
> The constraint will be checked immediately, so the table data must satisfy the constraint before it can be added.

I don't understand what it means by *"which cannot be written as a table constraint"*?

What is table constraint? What constraint doesn't check immediately?

Comment: Why are you reading such an outdated version of the manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a question of syntax.

A column constraint is defined like

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
   col type [CONSTRAINT name] constraint_definition,
   ...
);
```

while a table constraint look like

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
   col type,
   [CONSTRAINT name] constraint_definition,
   ...
);
```

The resulting constraint is the same in both cases.

So the documentation is saying that you need to write `NOT NULL` in the column definition and you cannot write it anywhere else.